# Integrate $\int_D 2e^{-x^2}$ with $D = \lbrace (x,y) \in \Bbb{R}^2 | 0\le x \le 1, 0 \le y \le x \rbrace$

Tags: integration

I was given the following task but I don't know how to keep going.
The task is:

> Integrate $\int_D 2e^{-x^2}$   with $D = \lbrace (x,y) \in \Bbb{R}^2 |
> > 0\le x \le 1, 0 \le y \le x \rbrace$

I started with the following integral:

$$\int_0^1 \int_0^x 2\cdot e^{-x^2}dy\;dx$$
$$=\int_0^1  \left[2\cdot e^{-x^2} \right]_0^xdx$$
$$=\int_0^1  x\cdot2\cdot e^{-x^2}dx$$

I am stuck at evaluating this integral.
I assumed that $erf(x)$ will appear.

The thing is that my university published the solution:

$$\int_D 2e^{-x^2} = 1 - \dfrac{1}{e}$$

I would be very happy if someone could explain to me, what I did wrong.

Greetings,
Finn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In $I=\int 2xe^{x^2}dx$,
let $y=x^2$.

Then $dy = 2xdx$ so
$I=\int e^ydy$.

Comment: Oh.. Wow I feel pretty dumb now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are welcome. It's just the standard special case of $\int f'(x)e^{f(x)}dx = \int e^ydy = e^y = e^{f(x)}$ with $y = f(x)$.